# Wait for the first subprocess to finish

Tags: python, subprocess, wait

I have a list of `subprocess`' processes. I do not communicate with them and just wait.

I want to wait for the first process to finish (this solution works):

```py
import subprocess

a = subprocess.Popen(['...'])
b = subprocess.Popen(['...'])

# wait for the first process to finish
while True:
    over = False
    for child in {a, b}:
        try:
            rst = child.wait(timeout=5)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            continue  # this subprocess is still running

        if rst is not None:  # subprocess is no more running
            over = True
            break  # If either subprocess exits, so do we.
    if over:
        break
```

I don't want use `os.wait()`, cause it could return from another `subprocess` not part of the list I'm waiting for.

A nice and elegant solution would probably be with an `epoll` or select and without any loop.

Comment: why not use `.communicate`?

Comment: I think your solution is pretty elegant. Can you make the processes write something to stdout or stderr when they are done (and only when they are done)?

Comment: And another question - would you consider using something like https://pypi.org/project/psutil/?

Comment: The subprocesses do not write to stdout or stderr , I really do not want communicate with them. I did not knew about psutil , I will take a look , or maybe can you propose a solution with this lib ? Thanks

Comment: @raphaelauv - see my answer below. Apparently, they provide a specific function just for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using psutil - which is aimed *exactly* at this use-case:

```
import subprocess
import psutil

a = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sleep', "2"])

b = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sleep', "4"])

procs_list = [psutil.Process(a.pid), psutil.Process(b.pid)]

def on_terminate(proc):
     print("process {} terminated".format(proc))

# waits for multiple processes to terminate
gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(procs_list, timeout=3, callback=on_terminate)
```

Or, if you'd like to have a loop waiting for one of the process to be done:

```
while True: 
    gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(procs_list, timeout=3, callback=on_terminate) 
    if len(gone)>0: 
        break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Seems like doing the stuff, but the documentation do not ENSURE that this call will return if at least one process is gone

does this function could return an empty gone struct ?

Comment: Yes, it can. If you change the timeout to a lower number (e.g., 1), you'll get an empty 'gone' struct. If this answers your question, by the way, it would be great if you could accept my answer.

Comment: If it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept it.

Comment: My edit was refused but a correct answer would be : 

while True:
    gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(procs_list, timeout=3, callback=on_terminate)
    if len(gone)>0:
        break

Comment: Edited and added your loop. Again - if it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept it for future generations.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use [`os.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.wait) for this. You just have to call it in a loop until it tells you one of the processes you care about has exited.

```py
import subprocess

a = subprocess.Popen(['...'])

b = subprocess.Popen(['...'])


# wait for the first process to finish
watched_pids = set(proc.pid for proc in (a, b))
while True:
    pid, _ = os.wait()
    if pid in watched_pids:
        break
```

---

However, a hidden side effect of `os.wait()` is that you lose the process's exit code. It will just be `None` after `os.wait()` finishes, and if you later call `proc.wait()`, `proc.poll()`, or `proc.communicate()` they will fail to find the return code and default to 0. It is possible to set it yourself, but it's kind of hacky.

```py
def wait_and_handle_exitstatus(all_procs):
    pid, status = os.wait()
    for proc in all_procs:
        if proc.pid == pid:
            # We need to set the process's exit status now, or we
            # won't be able to retrieve it later and it will be
            # assumed to be 0.
            # This is a kind of hacky solution, but this function has existed
            # ever since subprocess was first included in the stdlib and is
            # still there in 3.10+, so it *should* be pretty stable.
            proc._handle_exitstatus(status)
    return pid, status
```

You can then use the first code block, only replace `os.wait()` with `wait_and_handle_exitstatus(ALL_PROCS)`. You do, however, have to pass `wait_and_handle_exitstatus` a list of all subprocesses (`Popen` objects) that might be running and you might care about the return code of, so it can find the process and set its exit code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to get output from the processes, `Popen.poll()` seems to be the simplest way to check whether they are done. The `while True` loop below is purely for demonstration purposes: you can decide how to do this in your larger program (eg, do the checking in a separate thread, do the checking in between the other work of the program, etc).

```
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

ps = [
    Popen(['sleep', t])
    for t in ('3', '5', '2')
]

while True:
    exit_codes = [p.poll() for p in ps]
    print(exit_codes)
    if any(ec is not None for ec in exit_codes):
        break
    else:
        sleep(1)
```

Demo output:

```
[None, None, None]
[None, None, None]
[None, None, 0]
```

Comment: There's a catch with Poll. In some cases, it returns the wrong result.

Comment: @Roy2012 Good to know. Is this problem documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes - but I was too lazy to find it :) Here a link: https://lists.gt.net/python/bugs/633489

Comment: My edit was refused , but a correct answer to the question would be

    if any(ec is not None for ec in exit_codes):
        break
    else:
        sleep(1)

Comment: The question is : wait for the FIRST subprocess to finish, not all . That's why i wanted to correct your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `asyncio.wait` or `asyncio.as_completed`:

```
import asyncio

async def example():
    p1 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("sleep", "1")
    p2 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("sleep", "2")
    p1_run = asyncio.create_task(p1.wait())
    p2_run = asyncio.create_task(p2.wait())
    pending = [p1_run, p2_run]
    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        if p1_run in done:
            print("p1 finished, with status: ", p1.returncode)
        if p2_run in done:
            print("p2 finished, with status: ", p2.returncode)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(example())
```

To avoid having to repeat which one of p1 and p2 that was done, you usually end up with a more complex mapping of the px_run to px.

To avoid that, another option is to wrap the task in something like `wait_and_return_original` below, next example also uses a more convenient `asyncio.as_completed`

```
async def wait_and_return_original(proc: asyncio.subprocess):
    await proc.wait()
    return proc

async def example2():
    p1 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("sleep", "1")
    p2 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("sleep", "2")
    
    for p in asyncio.as_completed([wait_and_return_original(p) for p in [p1, p2]]):
        p_completed = await p   # NOTE: for-loop iteration variable doesn't decide which task is first completed until here!
        if p_completed is p1:
            print("p1 finished, with status: ", p1.returncode)
        if p_completed is p2:
            print("p2 finished, with status: ", p2.returncode)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(example2())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty much 2 ways to do this, if you want the commands to be **blocking** and halt your program until it finishes, use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

```py
a = subprocess.call('...')
b = subprocess.call('...')
```

I don't think this is what you want though.

If you do not want them to halt your entire program and only need to check if one of them is finished before calling another, you should use [`.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

```py
a = subprocess.Popen(['...'])

b = subprocess.Popen(['...'])

....
    for child in {a, b}:
        try:
            result, err = child.communicate(timeout=5)
```

`.communicate` is pretty much the most elegant, simple and recommended solution

Comment: Thank for your answer , but I would prefer a none active waiting ( no while:True )

Also I do not want communicate with the subprocess