# Invoking msys2 shell from python script does not wait until execution is complete

Tags: python, msys2

I have a python script which invokes a bat-script in a msys2 shell:

```py
msysPath = "C:/msys64/msys2"
scriptFile = "C:/projects/test/msys_script.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen([msysPath, scriptFile])
p.wait()
```

The execution of the bat-script in the msys2 shell works just fine, but unfortunately the python script does not actually wait for completion and instead just continues immediately.

I tried several variations:

```
subprocess.call([msysPath, scriptFile])
```

```
p = subprocess.Popen([msysPath, scriptFile])
p.communicate()
```

```
subprocess.check_call( [msysPath, scriptFile] )
```

In each case, the msys2 shell starts up and executes the script file, but the python script continues immediately despite msys2 still processing the commands.

I can execute other processes from python and wait for them just fine, it just doesn't appear to work with msys2 specifically. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467974/wait-for-the-first-subprocess-to-finish